# How to save and fetch one Object from Database in Swift?

Tags: ios, database, core-data, swift

I have a method which will save Object into Database. As per logic, whenever there is internet, it will save object by downloading from server.The method is as follows.

```
func saveConfiguration (config : ConfigDao){

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("AppConfig", inManagedObjectContext:self.del.managedObjectContext!)

        let configurationContext = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.del.managedObjectContext!) as AppConfig

        configurationContext.categoriesVer = Int32(config.categoriesVer)
        configurationContext.fireBallIp = config.fireBallIP
        configurationContext.fireBallPort = Int32(config.fireBallPort)
        configurationContext.isAppManagerAvailable = config.isAppManagerAvailable
        configurationContext.isFireBallAvailable = config.isFireballAvailable
        configurationContext.timePerQuestion = config.timePerQuestion


    }
```

Issue is that this adds all objects, and doesn't replace it, so my first query is

"How to add only one object in DB and replace when next Object comes?"

I also want to retrieve the same object, the only one object, normally in array, I do fetch last index, but how can I save only one and fetch same in DB.

```
func fetchAppConfig() -> AppConfig {

        var fetchRequest =  NSFetchRequest (entityName: "AppConfig")

        var error : NSError?
        let fetchResults = del.managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [NSManagedObject]

        if error != nil {
            println ("Error \(error)")
        }

        return  fetchResults
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do as following.

**//For storing only one object,**

```
func saveConfiguration (config : ConfigDao){

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("AppConfig", inManagedObjectContext:self.del.managedObjectContext!)
        var fetchRequest =  NSFetchRequest (entityName: "AppConfig")

        if let fetchResults = del.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [AppConfig] {
            for ob: AppConfig in fetchResults
            {
                println("Delete object,,, ")
                self.del.managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(ob as AppConfig)
            }
            self.del.saveContext()
        }

        let configurationContext = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.del.managedObjectContext!) as AppConfig

        configurationContext.categoriesVer = Int32(config.categoriesVer)
        configurationContext.fireBallIp = config.fireBallIP
        configurationContext.fireBallPort = Int32(config.fireBallPort)
        configurationContext.isAppManagerAvailable = config.isAppManagerAvailable
        configurationContext.isFireBallAvailable = config.isFireballAvailable
        configurationContext.timePerQuestion = config.timePerQuestion

        del.saveContext()

    }// end of the
```

**//To fetch object at zero index. which will be only one, still you can  use 0 index to be sure.**

```
func fetchAppConfig() -> AppConfig {

        var appConfig:AppConfig = AppConfig()

        var fetchRequest =  NSFetchRequest (entityName: "AppConfig")

        var error : NSError?
        if let fetchResults = del.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [AppConfig] {

            if error != nil {
                println ("Error \(error)")
            }
            appConfig = fetchResults[0]
        }

        return appConfig
    }
```